# How to pagination with one-to-many relationship tables in sql?

Tags: sql

Basically I want to write an API, client will say "I want to get 5 books, and i need to know how many books do you have" and api should return first 5 book and total book count.

I have Book Table and Each book can be translate more than one language, so I keep it in separate table.

This is my **Books Table**:

[image]

And this is **BookLanguages Table**:

[image]

Client calls: `api/books?index=0&take=5`
Expected result:

```
{
  Books:
  [
    {
        "Name": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
        "Languages": "en,de,ch"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix",
        "Languages": "en,ch"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince",
        "Languages": "en,ch"
    },
    {
        "Name": "The Hobbit",
        "Languages": "ch,de"
    },
    {
        "Name": "The Fellowship Of The Ring",
        "Languages": "ch,en"
    }
  ],
  TotalCount:8
}
```

My Result:

```
{
  Books:
  [
    {
        "Name": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
        "Languages": "en,de,ch"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix",
        "Languages": "en,ch"
    }
  ],
  TotalCount:8
}
```

My sql code looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Books B
LEFT JOIN BookLanguages L ON L.BookId = B.Id
```

**Joined table** looks like:

[image]

And I'm taking 5 rows with `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY` . So it gives only 2 distinct books. But as you know I need 5 distinct books with their languages.

**Expected Joined Table (it gets first 5 book in somehow which is my question)**
[image]

**Constraint:** API also has language and color filtering option. So I can not first take 5 Books and than join with BookLanguages Table. (API could be `api/books?index=0&take=5&language=ch`)

**Note**: Of course books is not my real problem I just want to make problem simple. I have to make more than one join (which has one-to-many relationships)

I'm using mssql

Answer (score -3):

Solution after the question was clarified

```
    SELECT b.id,
        b.name,
        b.color,
        bl.language
    FROM books b
        JOIN booklanguages bl ON
            bl.bookid = b.id
    WHERE b.id >= (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books ORDER BY id OFFSET 15) AND
       b.id <= (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books ORDER BY id OFFSET 19)
    ORDER BY b.id, bl.language
```

Just change the 15 and 19 to the required values to change the range selected for your pagination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment but as I said its just simple example to describe my problem I have lots of different tables to join in one to many relationship and I cannot join discreate languages like that. I edit my question and added my expected sql result.

Comment: Hi, to add color filter you just need to add a WHERE clause as the color is in the book table, you can use a sub-select in the WHERE clasue to filter to books by language as well. Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: I need to get the expected sql result (the highlighted rows) that I show in last image. I will give it to dapper to get my api result.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer

Comment: I need to do pagination, if I want the first 5 book, i should get the result that I show, if second 5, it should get next 5 books with related rows. It doesnt make any sense making it with id restrictions as u show

Comment: I've added some more to explain how the id references would work

Comment: As I said just replace the 0 and 5 with some code to move the numbers to the correct values